# Obtaining values from ipywidgets.widgets.SelectMultiple

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am not able to get the values from a MultipleSelect widget after changing the initial selection. The selection looks fine, but the values do not show. The code to create the SelectMultiple widget:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
w = widgets.SelectMultiple(description="Fruits",
options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'])
display(w)
```

The selection widget appears as expected, and if nothing is done with it, a subsequent `w.value` correctly returns the visual selection (for me, this is the last option, 'Pears'). 
However, after making a selection by mouse (say, selecting 'Apples' or 'Apples' and 'Oranges'), `w.value` returns an empty tuple.

The exact same code with `widgets.SelectMultiple` replaced with `widgets.Dropdown` works as expected (`w.value` showing the selected value, also after changing the selection).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it to be a browser issue. I usually use Chrome, where it works just fine. Today, I used IE11, and whereas all other `ipywidgets.widgets` worked as expected, the `widgets.SelectMultiple` does not.